# wireless internet connectivity not detected

Tags: 11.10, wireless

i have a lenovo laptop (2.1 GHz, 2 GB RAM, 500 GB Hard) with windows 7 ultimate. i installed ubuntu 11.10 today. when i restarted it quickly gave a message "error file..." and then ubuntu started. i have a wifi internet connection which is detected by windows 7 but ubuntu does not detect it. when i try to select "enable wireless" from networking menu, nothing happens, it is never selected despite repeated clicks. if i try to add a wireless connection through "edit connections" at the bottom of the menu, the save button never gets enabled in the window regardless whatever i do. i reinstalled ubuntu after uninstalling it but the problem persists. please give the solution in simple language because i am not into computer language.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons you cannot connect may be that the router does not broadcast it's SSID.
You must log into the router, and change that.  Second: get the name of the router and the password of the wireless section.  Provide these to the network connection to get the connection established.  Not knowing what router you have I can't give the exact details.
The above worked with my DLink router.

you should have a wireless icon in the top panel.
click that icon
then select "Create New Wireless Network
Provide the name of the home network
set the encryption to what is used by the router
enter the password to the home network and finish.

The laptop should find it as long as the broadcast SSID is turned on.

Hope this helps